# Is there a coding standard for PHP annotations?

Tags: php, coding-style

Is there a PHP coding standard that defines unambiguously how to write docblock annotations for properties and methods:

- `@var`
- `@param`
- `@return`
- `@throws`

including the correct spacing between them?

[PSR-2](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md) covers the code itself, but does not enforce the usage of annotations.

Comment: This becomes even more interesting when you consider that frameworks like Symfony2 actually use those annotations as a form of macrocoding

Comment: They use the Doctrine Common annotations library, which has somewhat become a standard among frameworks. But it looks like there is no "official" standard neither for these annotations, nor for the phpDoc ones, sadly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no annotations in PHP. If you use `phpdoc` to generate documentation, you need to follow `phpdoc` guides.

http://www.phpdoc.org/

Comment: Yes, I mean phpDoc annotations, but while phpDoc is a de-facto standard, it's not the only documentation tool available. Furthermore, it fails to define the proper spacing etc. for annotations, AFAIK. I was hoping that there was a defined standard somewhere that documentation tools would be built upon.

Comment: Thanks anyway for your answer. For information, I asked a similar question regarding [whether a PHPCS standard exists for this purpose](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13767550/759866).