# Is there a PHPCS standard targeting PHP docblocks?

Tags: php, phpdoc, phpcodesniffer

Is there a PHPCS coding standard that would check that proper annotations (`@param`, `@return`, `@throws`, etc.) are present in a docblock, including the proper spacing between them?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try running the following command and see if it produces what you want:

`phpcs /path/to/code --standard=Squiz --sniffs=Squiz.Commenting.FunctionComment,Squiz.Commenting.FunctionCommentThrowTag,Squiz.Commenting.ClassComment,Squiz.Commenting.FileComment,Squiz.Commenting.VariableComment`

If it does, you could create your own standard that just includes those sniffs, and anything else you want to check. You do this by creating a `ruleset.xml` file and using that as your standard.

For example, you could create a file called `mystandard.xml` and include the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="MyStandard">
  <description>My custom coding standard.</description>
  <rule ref="Squiz.Commenting.FunctionComment" />
  <rule ref="Squiz.Commenting.FunctionCommentThrowTag" />
  <rule ref="Squiz.Commenting.ClassComment" />
  <rule ref="Squiz.Commenting.FileComment" />
  <rule ref="Squiz.Commenting.VariableComment" />
</ruleset>
```

Then you can run this command instead:

```
phpcs /path/to/code --standard=/path/to/mystandard.xml
```

There are other things you can do in a `ruleset.xml` file. See the docs here: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Annotated-Ruleset

Comment: This answer is from 2012. It is still correct. But I would add that today, you can also use the Generic.Commenting.DocComment sniff. These sniffs behave just a little differently, so pick the one that's best for your style.

Comment: Recommend throwing on `-s` to the phpcs argument list; it'll show exact which sniff was triggered by your code, which is useful for debugging and building your rule list.

Answer (score 9):

In 2017 you have now more options:

- one of the **best sniffs to check docblocks is [TypeHintDeclarationSniff from SlevomatCodingStandard](https://github.com/slevomat/coding-standard/blob/master/SlevomatCodingStandard/Sniffs/TypeHints/TypeHintDeclarationSniff.php)**, works great with PHP 7, PHP 7.1, drop unused docs etc.
- also you can **make use of another tool - [PHP-CS-Fixer](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/)**, there you can find more fixers, that will help you with docblock, just search "doc"

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I'm author of Rector.*

**In 2019** you can use static analysis **to complete `@var` types or type declarations** for you.

```
class SomeClass
{
    private $value;

    public setValue(string $string)
    {
        // here we know the string type is assigned
        $this->value = $value;
    }    
}
```

Knowing that, Rector autocomplete the var type:

```
class SomeClass
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $value;

    public setValue(string $string)
    {
        $this->value = $value;
    }    
}
```

Similar approach works for return type, PHP 7.4 types and type declarations from parent interfaces and classes. All supported by Rector.

Read more in [How to Complete Type Declarations without Docblocks with Rector](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2019/01/03/how-to-complete-type-declarations-without-docblocks-with-rector/#properties-without-code-var-code)