# PHPCS / PHPMD : Is there a PHP Code Sniffer / Mess Detector way to ensure there are docblocks?

Tags: php, phpmd, phpcs

Is there a way I can use PHP Code Sniffer and/or PHP Mess Detector to detect if my classes/properties/methods have proper docblocks? For example:

```
class Foo
{
    protected $bar;

    public function doStuff(){
        // ...
    }
}
```

The above example should raise red flags. However, the following example should pass:

```
/**
 * Class Foo
 * @package Vendor\Module
 */
class Foo
{
    /**
     * @var Vendor\Module\Model\Bar
     */
    protected $bar;

    /**
     * This method does stuff
     * @return bool
     */
    public function doStuff(){
        // ...
    }
}
```

I'm not per definition interested if the docblocks are correct (if the return types match that what is returned), I mean: it would be nice if it also does that, but the first step I want to take is the ensure that the docblocks are present.

Comment: @LukasHajdu: I looked at that answer, but if I'm not mistaking that question is more about validating if what's inside the docblock is valid, rather than check if the docblock is present at all. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I've added 2 new options in 2017 to the duplicated question. Check it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43722973/1348344

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution from [duplicated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767550/is-there-a-phpcs-standard-targeting-php-docblocks) is working for the docblock presence check as well.

This is my **Bar** class which has comments:

```
<?php

namespace PhpCSTesting;

use stdClass;

/**
 * Class Bar
 */
class Bar
{
    /**
     * @var stdClass
     */
    protected $bar;

    /**
     * This method does stuff
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function doStuff()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I run the sniffer I get no errors:

```
bin/phpcs Bar.php --standard=Squiz --sniffs=Squiz.Commenting.FunctionComment,Squiz.Commenting.FunctionCommentThrowTag,Squiz.Commenting.ClassComment,Squiz.Commenting.VariableComment
```

This is my **Foo** class which has no comments:

```
<?php

namespace PhpCSTesting;

class Foo
{
    protected $bar;

    public function doStuff()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

However, when I run the sniffer for this class I get errors:

```
bin/phpcs Foo.php --standard=Squiz --sniffs=Squiz.Commenting.FunctionComment,Squiz.Commenting.FunctionCommentThrowTag,Squiz.Commenting.ClassComment,Squiz.Commenting.VariableComment

FILE: /Users/lukas/workspace/Foo.php
----------------------------------------------------------------------
FOUND 3 ERRORS AFFECTING 3 LINES
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 5 | ERROR | Missing class doc comment
 7 | ERROR | Missing member variable doc comment
 9 | ERROR | Missing function doc comment
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You can update and modify ruleset based on your needs.